# Which file attributes are stored in the directory entries and which in the inodes?

Tags: filesystems, file-attributes, inode

I want to do some deduplication of old files, replacing duplicates with hardlinks.

To minimize loss of metadata, I want to set the directory entry attributes of each new hardlink to the attributes of the duplicate it replaces, but not change any inode attributes of the inode that gets the new links.

Which properties should I set and not set?

Ideally, I'd like to see a table showing what's where in as many filesystems as possible.  I'm particularly interested in ext3, ext4, HFS+, XFS, and Btrfs.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not possible in any file system I know of, because of how they are implemented, as described here.  And I don't understand why you'd be concerned about the meta data, to begin with?

First, the only data in the directory entry is the filename and the inode number.

Second, a hard link is made when you create two or more file names with the **same** inode number.

The inode stores everything else, things like atime and mtime, and other meta data, including "pointers" to the data blocks of the file.

If you have two files whose contents are the same, but the inodes are different, most of the meta data in the inodes will be different, for example the mentioned atime and mtime will be different, as will *all* of the data block pointers.

To use a hard link to reduce storage usage, you would delete one or the other of the duplicated files, which will also "close" the inode, losing all the meta data.  You then create a link to the remaining existing file, using the name and directory location of the file you just deleted.

The "new" file link will now have **all** the same inode information as the one you just linked to.  The only differences will be the location in the directory hierarchy and the name used, which are stored in the directory entry, not the inode.

All of this is handled through the system calls used to create files, links and directories, and is not directly modifiable by any user or software, including 'root'.  You could read it, and store the data in a separate file, but the easy association of a directory hierarchy will be lost.

Comment: If I understand you right, your answer amounts to "only the names are stored in the directory entries, all other properties are stored in the inodes".  Is that what you mean?  That matches the results of my simple empirical test on ext3 and HFS+; do you know what other filesystems work that way?  (It's not all filesystems, in particular, not NTFS.)  Do you know if that include xattrs and/or ACLs?  Can you link to documentation?

Comment: As I said in the post, the directory entry also has the inode number, so the system can find the file data and other meta-data.

Comment: Yes, everything else is in the inode (see the stat(2) man page on any Linux or UNIX system).  I know nothing about how NTFS or other M$ filesystems work, your question as I understood it was about Linux/UNIX file systems.  So far as I know, all native Linux and UNIX filesystems work this way.  Note that NTFS support in Linux may be limited, depending on your distribution.

Comment: Could you explain what it is in the metadata that you need to preserve?